# As3 Movieclip loaded in container reports exaggerated .width value

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3, movieclip, moviecliploader

I am trying to load a swf(as3) into another As3 Swf with the Movieclip loader. After loading however Loader.width/loader.content.width returns an exaggerated value than the actual width of the swf being loaded. Any pointers on where to begin looking for the discrepancy?
Thanks in advance.

*More Details (if it helps)*

The swf being loaded has UI components like dropdowns, input boxes and combo boxes (its a Form to fill up), and a coded one-time tween.

When the child MC loads into the parent movieclip, the Loader.width value returned is exaggerated by about 28 pixels (although the height remains the same). Loader.content.width also returns a 28 pixel exaggerated value. The Exaggerated value is more than even the stage width of the child MC. The extra ~30 px are upsetting subsequent code in the parent movie to scale and center the loaded swf.

update:

stage.stageWidth returns the correct Value.

Code used in the parent MC, to load external SWF:

```
private var deadURL = "child.swf";
private var deadReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(deadURL);
private var deadLoader:Loader = new Loader();
deadLoader.load(deadReq);
deadLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDeadLoad);


public function onDeadLoad(e:Event):void
{
addChild(deadLoader);
trace("content.width: " + deadloader.content.width); //returns exaggerated value
trace("width: " + deadLoader.width); //returns same exaggerated value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code you are using to load the external SWF?
In which method are you reading the width/height value?
Which value do the following code return when executed inside the external swf?

```
trace(stage.stageWidth);
trace(stage.stageHeight);
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Updated the original Question with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent MC is resized i.e. if in the Transform dialog it reads other than 100% then that transformation is passed on to any children.